# Visual Studio - Adding New Item - Why so few options available?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with an old ASP.Net Webforms application. When trying to add a new item (such as an aspx page or class), I am only getting the following options:

[image]

On other "modern" projects, I get to see full options. Under 'Online', there is nothing available. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search this up on your apps. If it is available, you should be able to download and install plugins and "modern" projects there.
[image]

Click on modify.
[image]

Then choose desired platforms.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I needed to select the option 'Additional project templates (previous versions)' under 'Optional' for ASP.Net workload. That solved the problem.